# Saving decoded HTML with Kendo editor and Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use Kendo editor with angular but I cannot find any useful post.

I tried using `ng-bind-html` but no luck because every time I reopen the editor, it gives me the decoded version of the html. No luck with `$sce.trustAsHtml()` either.

I'm using the following hack to decode:

```
function decodeHtml(text) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = text;
    return txt.value;
}
```

within my controller

```
$scope.persist = function (form) {
    $scope.item.text = decodeHtml($scope.item.text);
    $scope.save(form);
}
```

and here is my HTML

```
<textarea kendo-editor ng-model="item.text" name="text" k-encode="false"></textarea>
```

Everything is working fine except when I try to unit test this method. I tried replacing `document.createElement` with `angular.element`. Maybe I should extract the `decodeHtml` to its own dependency.

My jasmine test :

```
describe('when persisting changes', function() {

    var form = {};

    beforeEach(function () {
        scope.item = { text: '%3C' }; // UTF-8 encoding for < character
        scope.persist(form);
    });

    it('should decode HTML', function() {
        expect(scope.item.text).toEqual('<');
    });

});
```

Any thoughts please ...